# Why is my render color vastly different to the color in the material preview mode?

Tags: rendering

On the left is my model using `cycles rendering`. On the right is the model in `object preview` mode.

Why is my model darker in the `cycles render` instead of the `object preview`?

[image]

Comment: I was going to say "lighting" but it seems you discovered that yourself. One thing to note is that your viewport on the right is just "material preview" mode so it doesn't render full lighting and will likely never match an actual render.

Comment: @DaleCieslak thank you for prompting me to update my post with the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that *material preview* mode only shows you the most basic of lighting.

To see what the actual render will look like, you **must look at the EEVEE or CYCLES render preview.**

This can be accomplished by holding `Z` and moving the mouse to `Rendered`

The recommended workflow is to work mainly in *material preview* mode when moving objects around - and swapping to EEVEE in the viewport for previewing the final render.

Once you become more proficient at blender, you will know when working with CYCLES is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the blend file my guess is that you might have changed the object color under Object Properties - Viewport Display and also applied a color as a material or node giving you two different results.